# MongoDB lookup one record per each value in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to make a custom lookup that allow me to only get one item per each value.

example:

source record:

```js
{
  ...
  "names": [ "name 1", "name 2", "name 3" ],
  ...
  
}
```

records to populate:

```js
{ "name": "name 1", "id": 1 },   // populate
{ "name": "name 1", "id": 2 },   // ignore
{ "name": "name 2", "id": 3 },   // populate
{ "name": "name 2", "id": 4 },   // ignore 
{ "name": "name 3", "id": 5 },   // populate
```

so what I need here to only populate `id 1, and id 3 and id 5`, which means only one record per each name.

I used `$group` and it works fine but it was very slow for 500 million records DB.

so is there a way in the lookup pipeline to fetch only one record per value.

Answer (score 0):

In the `$lookup` subpipeline, use `$group` to get only the `$first` record per group. `$replaceRoot` to wrangle to your desired form.

```js
db.source.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "names",
      "localField": "names",
      "foreignField": "name",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            record: {
              "$first": "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$record"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "names"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UVgcBRkveiE)

Comment: as I mentioned this is the current implementation, but it is too slow (about 17seconds) even slower than making multiple quires `findOne` for all source records.

Comment: @hegazy How you index your collections?

Comment: I have an index for the property name, when I make only a lookup without `$group` it took only 23ms but with `$group` then `$replaceRoot`, it took 17s, 

I think the `$group` slow because we have thousands of records that share same name.
the number of source collection about 160 million records and the target collection is 530 million records.

Comment: @hegazy you can try several things: 1. index also the names field in source collection to speed up the `$lookup` 2. refactor your schema to store only the first record in target collection(potentially through a unique index)

Comment: the index works fine, as you see the lookup only take 23ms so it is supper fast, and I indexed the name property and the source names property.
the second solution is good, but unfortunately the business needs many records and in specific case we need to pick the first record per each name, I think the best solution is to add a flag to mark the first record per each name and in the lookup I can query only these records with the `flag: true`

Comment: @hegazy You may want to check out [materialized view](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/materialized-views/), which could be helpful to your case.